# How to do setting for socket.io before deploying to live server for mern stack project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, mern

In order to implement real-time functionality I have configured socket.io in my mern stack project.Locally it is establishing a connection successfully but creating problem when I deployed my front-end and backened in live server . I Need guidance on setting socket.io in production mode. this is my frontend setting:

```
  const ENDPOINT = 'https://api.mywebapi.net';
  const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT,{
    forceNew: true,
    origins: 'https://api.mywebapi.net',
  });
and this is backend setting:   


const server = http.createServer(app); // mount socket.io server
const io = new Server(server,{
  pingTimeout:60000,
  cors:{
    origin:["http://localhost:3000",
    "http:localhost",
    'https://desktopapp.net',
    'http://15.15.30.64'
    
  ],
    methods:["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
    

  }

});
```

Can anyone please guide me on it.
Your help will really appreciated with these changes mentioned above it is not establishing connection with client and server and throw error of 400 bad request in Get and post

I have tryied my best to sort this issue but couldn't .There is no specific help available online. I need guidance on how to do setting of socket.io before deploying in live server.